# Consuming time consuming web service through javascript

Tags: javascript

I am not a javascript expert (obviously). I am trying to call a web service which will execute a time consuming operation (send an email). I am doing this through a get request executed from javascript client, using the below code.

```
$.get(targetURL, function(response) {
    console.log("Got response "+response);
});
```

If I don't block the javascript until the web service finishes execution and returns its answer, the email is not sent. Why is this? I would expect that since the request is sent, the web service will execute regardless if the javascript code waits for the answer or not. What am I missing here? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What you mean by `waits for answer or not`? If you close window before request is done, than it will be terminated.

Comment: Could you provide the code that happens after this get request?

Comment: Perhaps I am not explaining it clearly. The $.get... is called regardlessly of the rest of the execution workflow. However, if javascript continues executing immediately, then the form is submitted and the system goes to another page. However, I would expect the web service to send the email and it does not (unless I delay or cancel the submission of the form)

Comment: Could you have the mail send from the page that handles the form submission since it seems to be tied to that action?

Comment: @spaniol6 I am sending the email from the submitted form, just before submission (is this that you are suggesting?). However, if submission is executed without any delay, the email is not sent. Is this normal?

Comment: The execution of the service is stopping because you're navigating away from the page that requested it before it completes, so I'm suggesting execute the submission and then send the email on the page that handles that submission.

Comment: @spaniol6 Thank you very much for your time and your suggestion. What you suggest seems logical. I think I came up with an explanation... I will provide it as an answer as it might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is that the web service called is sending the email on the **same thread** that the request is accepted. When the web page executing the javascript (acting as HTTP client) is submitted, the uncompleted **HTTP request is interrupted**. Therefore, the web service method does not execute and therefore the email is never sent. If the web service sends the email on another thread, the problem will probably be solved.